# How to access and read data from a play console KPI from a backend server?

Tags: android, backend, google-play-console, kpi

I need to read the data from one of my Android App's Play Console KPIs (engagement, total number of downloads etc.) from our backend server.

Is there any method to do so? I was looking for an API but couldn't find any. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Play Developer Reporting API**

Here is the link you can follow -
https://developers.google.com/play/developer/reporting/overview